# Android : canvas.drawoval() + rotation

Tags: android, canvas, rotation

I'd like to draw an oval, but I'd like to be able to rotate it. I know that I can use `canvas.drawOval(...)` and `canvas.rotate(...)`.  However, I want to just rotate my oval and not the whole canvas; that is, I want to rotate my oval before draw it to the canvas.
I have successfully rotated a rect by manipulating the coordinates before drawing it, but that approach isn't working for me with the oval.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's canvas.save() and canvas.restore() to serve that purpose - i.e.

```
canvas.save();
canvas.rotate(90);
canvas.drawOval(....);
canvas.restore();
....//do other drawing
```